how to use virtual function in a kernel with ASLR enabled?
I'm writing my own kernel with rust.
While I'm trying to relocate my kernel to some high virtual address (eg. an offset +0xffffffff00000000), everything seems to work well except calling virtual functions (in rust: &dyn trait), such as using core::fmt.
I've done some tests to confirm it is &dyn can't work.
The riscv assembly code is like
ld  a1,24(a1)
jalr    a1

Before relocation, it jumps to the pc it should be.
After relocation and enable mmu, it still jumps to the old pc, but this address has no physical mapped.
I also tried different codegen arguments in rust and in linker, such as relocation-model=default|static|pie|pic|....
When use default or static, rust do not generate GOT.
In pie or pic, the modification of GOT seems necessary, but I don't know the detailed method.

The executable has code references in static/global data, and those will have relocations that must be handled by linker or loader.
